# Fallback to backup server upon failure of main server without third machine

Tags: backup, postgresql, local-area-network, database-backup

I will soon need to setup a database server on a budget. We are planning to use Postgres on Ubuntu (most likely) and we'd like to have a backup server. For replication, I think I'll just use Postgres's [Streaming Replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION). It does all that I need and is simple to set up.

But what if the main server fails and we need the backup? Is there a way to route data to the backup without a third computer?

Let's say my main computer has the domain name `PG-MAIN` and my backup has the domain name `PG-BACKUP`. If I had a third computer I could (for example) check to see if `PG-MAIN` is up and if it is down, rename `PG-BACKUP` to `PG-MAIN`. Then, any query sent to `PG-MAIN` would still succeed. Maybe that would be a bad solution. I don't actually know. (Although [this Server Fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/298990/keeping-two-servers-in-sync-secondary-server-only-to-be-booted-for-the-backup) says it's a bad idea to use DNS that way.)

But is there a way for the backup to silently take the place of the main computer upon failure without the use of a third computer? I can't think of anything. And by "failure", I mean like the database daemon stops responding or a piano falls on the computer.

If it turns out to be absolutely, positively impossible, what would be cost-effective way of handling the fallback? The client applications will be custom-made. Should the logic of fallback part of the system be handled by the client applications? (That last part sounds like a *very* bad idea.)

Comment: Are you talking about `Postgres` H.A ?

Comment: @krisFR Yes, I mean the streaming replication that's part of Postgres High Availability.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you read this : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION In that case what have you tried that is not working ?

Comment: We haven't actually built anything yet. My issue is: if computer 1 fails but the data is still on computer 2, is there a way to route connections to the second computer without using a third computer, such as a DNS. I don't think there is.

Comment: Seems you are more concerned by a server problem than a pure DB problem...in both cases something like [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org) should work for you as it provides a VIP for a given service that you can monitor on each node

Comment: repmgr + pgbouncer or haproxy. Failback is painful at the moment, but see pg_rewind.